# Why is Vimium's default setting for "Characters used for link hints" the value "sadfjklewcmpgh"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

The "Characters used for link hints" section in the chrome extension Vimium is by default this:

```
sadfjklewcmpgh
```

I'm curious why that is?

Comment: It’s partially likely a mistake: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/21#issuecomment-468338013

Answer (score 1):

These are the letters on the home row plus a few more that are easily accessible. It's probably to make navigating with the (F)ind shortcut quicker.